# Refactor method to throw at most one checked exception instead of ExecutionException and InterruptedException

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have a method like

```
public void methodName() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {}
```

SonarQube raises an issue on this method, suggesting to refactor this code.

If I replace those exceptions with `Exception` (which both of them extend), then it says throwing `Exception` is too generic.

How can I resolve this issue?

Exact sonarQube message: Refactor this method to throw atmost one checked exception instead of ExecutionException , InterruptedException

Detailed Hint by sonarQube: https://sbforge.org/sonar/rules/show/squid:S1160?layout=false

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to add the exact details of that sonarqube message.

Comment: @GhostCat , I have added sonarQube message . Do you need any other details ?

Comment: I assume SonarQube gives a *more detailed* hint for the current code?

Comment: look here, at the first answer, all is explain :https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/263874/why-shouldnt-a-method-throw-multiple-types-of-checked-exceptions

Comment: What does the rule description advise?

Comment: @MaxenceLecointe I got the fact regarding not using it , but what to do when the function is executing something which can throw 2 different types of Exception.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam the rule description adviced this https://sbforge.org/sonar/rules/show/squid:S1160?layout=false

Comment: @GhostCat sonarQube gave this hint https://sbforge.org/sonar/rules/show/squid:S1160?layout=false

Comment: Don't put such information into comments. Update your question instead.

Comment: @GhostCat thanks , I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have the answer for you, but I guess it might be worth looking more in depth at the Exceptions. I looked up the following definitions on docs.oracle.com:

ExecutionException:
Exception thrown when attempting to retrieve the result of a task that aborted by throwing an exception. This exception can be inspected using the Throwable.getCause() method.

InteruptedException:
Thrown when a thread is waiting, sleeping, or otherwise occupied, and the thread is interrupted, either before or during the activity. Occasionally a method may wish to test whether the current thread has been interrupted, and if so, to immediately throw this exception. The following code can be used to achieve this effect:
  if (Thread.interrupted())  // Clears interrupted status!
      throw new InterruptedException();

That being said, maybe the nature of the ExecutionException means that we don't have to worry about catching the InteruptedException (since an ExcecutionException is thrown when mishandling another thrown exception). So maybe we try something like this:

```
public void methodName() throws ExecutionException {}
```